# How to split up array in Labview

Tags: labview

I got an u8 array where every 1,2,3 entry is the same, I'd like to cut this array down to one third of it's size. Like [240,240,240]->[240] and so on for the entire array. I'm not a skilled labview user, so this has proven quite an obstacle.

Anyone got a quick solution?

Regards,
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this ([decimate 1D array system primitive](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/glang/decimate_1d_array/)):

[image: code snipplet]

The icon is pretty much self describing. It takes ever 0,3,6...-th element of you array into a separate array, every 1,4,7,... -th element of your array into a second array and every 2,5,8 -th into a separate array. The icon is expandable for multiple outputs if you postion the cursor over lower right edge, and move the mouse while holding left mouse button (as Phil Brooks noted).

BTW, This is a snipplet, so you can download it to your computer, open folder in explorer and drag-and-drop onto your diagram (LV2014).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Decimate 1D array function.

Pull down on the function to show three outputs.

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/decimate_1d_array/